# HTML/CSS: Website in Firefox not displaying background, Chrome displays as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site that I used chrome developer tools to get working. However, when checking the site in Firefox, the background image is only viewable in a small strip in the middle of the page.

the code for my background image is the following:

```html
body {
  background-image: url(../assets/headerbackground.jpg);
  min-height: 0px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100vmax;
  -moz-background-size: 100vmax;
  -o-background-size: 100vmax;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/headerbackground.jpg',     sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/headerbackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

UPDATE:

Found the solution to my problem: My `<body>` had elements that were making it sandwich between the header and footer. Removing those elements from `<body>` did the trick.

Comment: Instead of linking out to the site, could you include a [mcve] inline as a snippet?  Once you update your site to resolve the issue, this question will become useless for new visitors because the reference code with the issue will no longer be available.  Furthermore, many users (including myself) are reluctant to click to outside sites that might contain malicious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to shave off the vendor prefixes, contain and cover have been well adopted for some time now.

https://caniuse.com/?search=background-size

```
body {
    background-image: url('../assets/headerbackground.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In addition to this, as a rule of thumb, I would remove the styling from the body tag and wrap the content of your site in something like `<div id="app"> ... </div>`. The `<html>` and `<body>` tags are rendered differently in each browser more than likely this is what is causing your site to display differently in separate browsers.
RMZ